# Are links in Powerpoint files supported in iOS Safari/UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, safari, powerpoint

I have a Powerpoint file with a link to another website. If you open the file in iOS Safari or in an app based on UIWebView, the link doesn't work.

You can test my file here: http://www.kioskproapp.com/tests/chris/Homepage.ppt

The blue/green square has the link.

Comment: UIWebView/mobileSafari can display specific document types, including ppt, word etc.. how are you loading the file. show code. Powerpoint is most certainly supported: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1630/_index.html

Comment: @Woodstock Could you test my file in iOS Safari and see if you're able to get the link to work? Also, I'm going to edit my question to be more specific.

Comment: @Woodstock Sorry, I realized I didn't say where the link was. It's the blue/green square.

Comment: Yup it works! Post your code and I will take a look.

Comment: Sorry, the powerpoint loads but touching the blue/green square does nothing. Opening on a desktop does nothing either!

Comment: Hyperlinks never do anything in normal view; you need to put the presentation in slideshow view to get the links to work.  On my iPhone 5, the link doesn't work in Safari, but Safari also offers to open the file in my choice of other installed apps (PPT, Keynote, etc).  If I open in PPT, the link works.

Comment: @Woodstock It just downloads the file when I try to open it on a desktop. I'm not sure if it's possible to view a PPT directly. Thanks for trying :)

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Do you mean I need to change the PPT presentation to 'slideshow view' before I save it? I need to display it without opening the PPT app, if possible.

Comment: @Grooms:  no, I suspect that Safari doesn't support links

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Thank you, that appears to be the case.